# Setting up static website project with TypeScript in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript, static-site

I can find only samples on how to set up a TypeScript project in conjuction with some server technology (ASP.NET Core for instance). I want to use Visual Studio in order to be able to write my client-side code in TypeScript which then gets transpiled down to JavaScript. However it just needs to be a static web site (from the server point of view). What project template do I need to choose or install? I was thinking about starting out with a ASP.NET Core project and then trimming out everything I don't need, but only if there is no better way.